# Icosahedron-Wrapping Monstrosity

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional, paper-folding

The following monstrosity of a shape:

[image: huge icosahedron-wrapping shape]

... can be wrapped onto the surface of an [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) in a way that completely covers the entire icosahedron with no gaps and no overlaps.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a picture of the solution.

> [image]
>  Once it was clear that the long hooks had to fold in on themselves rather than enclose something else, the rest followed.